# Clipping sound with opus on Android, sent from IOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, audiounit, opus

I am recording audio in IOS from audioUnit, encoding the bytes with opus and sending it via UDP to android side. **The problem is that the sound is playing a bit clipped**. I have also tested the sound by sending the Raw data from IOS to Android and it plays perfect.

My AudioSession code is

```
      try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
        try audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.02)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
```

My recording callBack code is:

```
func performRecording(
    _ ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBufNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus
 {
var err: OSStatus = noErr

err = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit!, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData)

if let mData = ioData[0].mBuffers.mData {
    let ptrData = mData.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: Int(inNumberFrames))
    let bufferPtr = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptrData, count: Int(inNumberFrames))

    count += 1
    addedBuffer += Array(bufferPtr)

    if count == 2 {

        let _ = TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&circularBuffer, addedBuffer, UInt32(addedBuffer.count * 2))

        count = 0
        addedBuffer = []

        let buffer = TPCircularBufferTail(&circularBuffer, &availableBytes)

        memcpy(&targetBuffer, buffer, Int(min(bytesToCopy, Int(availableBytes))))

        TPCircularBufferConsume(&circularBuffer, UInt32(min(bytesToCopy, Int(availableBytes))))

        self.audioRecordingDelegate(inTimeStamp.pointee.mSampleTime / Double(16000), targetBuffer)


    }
}
return err;
 }
```

Here i am getting **inNumberOfFrames** almost 341 and i am appending 2 arrays together to get a bigger framesize (needed 640) for Android but i am only encoding 640 by the help of TPCircularBuffer.

```
func gotSomeAudio(timeStamp: Double, samples: [Int16]) {

samples.count))



    let encodedData = opusHelper?.encodeStream(of: samples)
OPUS_SET_BITRATE_REQUEST)


    let myData = encodedData!.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        Data(buffer: $0)
    }

    var protoModel = ProtoModel()
    seqNumber += 1
    protoModel.sequenceNumber = seqNumber
    protoModel.timeStamp = Date().currentTimeInMillis()
    protoModel.payload = myData

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            try self.tcpClient?.send(data: protoModel)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
                             print("Time diff is \(diff)")
}
```

In the above code i am opus encoding 640 frameSize and adding it to ProtoBuf payload and Sending it via UDP.

On Android side i am parsing the Protobuf and decoding the 640 framesize and playing it with AudioTrack.There is no problem with android side as i have recorded and played sound just by using Android but the problem comes when i record sound via IOS and play through Android Side.

Please don't suggest to increase the frameSize by setting Preferred IO Buffer Duration. I want to do it without changing this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873492/12020007 It was helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947295/12020007
I have updated my code according to your suggestion, **removed the delegate** and **array concatenation** but there is still clipping on android side. I have also calculated the time it takes to encode bytes that is approx 2-3 ms.

Updated callback code is

```
var err: OSStatus = noErr
        // we are calling AudioUnitRender on the input bus of AURemoteIO
        // this will store the audio data captured by the microphone in ioData
        err = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit!, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData)

        if let mData = ioData[0].mBuffers.mData {

            _ = TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&circularBuffer, mData, inNumberFrames * 2)

            print("mDataByteSize: \(ioData[0].mBuffers.mDataByteSize)")
            count += 1

            if count == 2 {

                count = 0

                let buffer = TPCircularBufferTail(&circularBuffer, &availableBytes)

                memcpy(&targetBuffer, buffer, min(bytesToCopy, Int(availableBytes)))

                TPCircularBufferConsume(&circularBuffer, UInt32(min(bytesToCopy, Int(availableBytes))))

                let encodedData = opusHelper?.encodeStream(of: targetBuffer)


                let myData = encodedData!.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
                    Data(buffer: $0)
                }

                var protoModel = ProtoModel()
                seqNumber += 1
                protoModel.sequenceNumber = seqNumber
                protoModel.timeStamp = Date().currentTimeInMillis()
                protoModel.payload = myData

                    do {
                        try self.udpClient?.send(data: protoModel)
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

            }

        }
        return err;
```

Comment: You should listen for app/hardware state changes and for each state you can set custom frame size.

Comment: Try what? @AbdulRahmanAyub please stick to the topic.

Comment: @shyayan please increase the  frameSize, and let me know if the problem solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is doing Swift memory allocation (Array concatenation) and Swift method calls (your recording delegate) inside the audio callback.  Apple (in a WWDC session on Audio) recommends **not** doing any memory allocation or method calls inside the real-time audio callback context (especially when requesting short Preferred IO Buffer Durations).  Stick to C function calls, such as memcpy and TPCircularBuffer.

Added:  Also, don't discard samples.  If you get 680 samples, but only need 640 for a packet, keep the 40 "left over" samples and use them appended in front of a later packet.  The circular buffer will save them for you.  Rinse and repeat.  Send all the samples you get from the audio callback when you've accumulated enough for a packet, or yet another packet when you end up accumulating 1280 (2*640) or more.

Comment: I have updated my code according to your answer but still there is clipping sound on android. Where as raw data plays perfectly without opus encoding. The problem is we are getting 341-342 bytes but for opus encoding we need exactly 640 bytes. can you help me?

Comment: I am also facing a weird exception on recording that is repeating
AUTest[1096:344695] 55: EXCEPTION (-1): ""

but it appears it has no effect on my recording.

Comment: Encoding data and sending network data inside an audio callback is not recommended.  These activities can manage memory, call methods, and take locks.  All that should be done in a separate polling thread.

Comment: Thankyou for all your help hotpaw2 as you have added in your answer to not discard the leftover 40 samples, I am doing that as the remaining samples are appended the next time. I agree with you that encoding and network activities should not be done here but can you explain a bit more about a separate polling thread as I have a restriction of combining 2 packets of audio for the encoder.

Comment: In my testing, the encoder could be the problem as the callback keeps generating the data but the encoder couldn’t catch up and simply skips the data when another callback comes in which results in clipping on the android side. There isn’t constant clipping but it just clips sometimes in between which leads me to believe, the encoder is slow. Could you please guide me somehow how to make the callback and the encoder independent of each other maybe using a separate polling thread as you’ve said, can you guide me a little more?

Comment: How to deal with that problem (transferring data between 2 threads with different data size requirements) sounds like a good separate question. (e.g. not a comment)